# An iff proof concerning complete metric spaces and limits

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space, and $B \subseteq X$, then $B$ is a complete metric space iff any sequence $\{a_{n}\} \subseteq B$ that converges in $X$ has a limit in $B$.

$\Rightarrow$

Let $B \subseteq X$. If $\{a_{n}\} \in B$, then $\{a_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then $X$ has a limit point call it $a$, but $B \subseteq X$ so it must contain $a$ as well. Then $\{a_{n}\}$ converges in $B \Rightarrow B$ is complete.

Hopefully this is the right argument for one direction. I am unsure about the other direction though. I would greatly appreciate the $\Leftarrow$ direction as I have been pondering over it for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$

let us assume that $B\subset X$ is a complete metric subspace of $X$. let $\{a_n\}\subset B$ be a sequence that converge in $X$, then the sequence is cauchy in $X$, so it is also cauchy in $B$ and since $B$ is complete, then $\{a_n\}$ converges in $B$.

$\Leftarrow$

let us assume that any sequence in $B$ that converges in $X$ has a limit in $B$.

let $\{a_n\}\subset B$ be cauchy, it easy to see that $\{a_n\}$ is also cauchy in $X$, $X$ is complete so  $\{a_n\}$ converges in $X$, so by our assumption $\{a_n\}$ has a limit point in $B$ e.g it converges in $B$